why Application-based cookie stickiness is not binding user with ec2 instance?
i have started AWS certified solution architect course from udemy but while enabling "Appliction based cookie" stickiness i noticed that my load balancer is still routing me to different EC2 instance while "load balancer based cookie" stickiness was binding me to one specific instance.
i was trying to enable "Application based cookie" stickiness and was expecting that my requests will bind to one specific instance after enabling stickiness

Check that both EC2 instances are healthy. Perhaps try from a different Browser, or use an Incognito window to avoid the stickiness cookie?

With application-based stickiness the ALB is expecting the target instance to create a cookie when the client connects to it. The behaviour is documented here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html#application-based-stickiness in the AWS documentation. This custom cookie must match what is set on the load balancer.
